# Ethernet ports not working after re-applying AC power

Tags: linux-kernel, ethernet, yocto

I have a device which runs `yocto` embedded system. The device has `Super Capacitors(supercap)` to provide few mins backup when AC power supply is abruptly pulled off. Please note when device is on `Supercap`, peripherals power are cut to provide little more time to CPU for safe shutdown.

Ethernet ports do not work(not even LED blinks on ports) in following scenarios:

- AC is pulled off so device gets power from `Supercap`(and as result Ethernet ports are abruptly suspended I assumed)
- Re-apply AC power when device is on `supercap` and ethernet ports do not come up again

NOTE: `r8169` kernel driver is being used for ethernet.

There are some suggestions out there to remove and insert `r8169` driver but the driver is an inbuilt module in kernel and I have a feeling that, it is not proper way to fix the problem. There should be some initialization/configuration to fix this.

I also tried couple of commands like "ifconfig enp2s0 up/down" but nothing worked out.